# custom error field combining 2 error fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

In my form, which is a credit card validation form, I have 2 fields `expiry_year` and `expiry_month`.

```
  validates :expiry_month,
            length: { is: 2, allow_blank: true },
            numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_blank: true }
  validates :expiry_year,
            length: { is: 4, allow_blank: true },
            numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_blank: true }
```

However I want to have a hidden Expiry field which shows as red in the form if the 2 fields above are not valid.

So the form will look something like this, but I need the Expiry label to be red in the validation, How can I do this?

[image]
Here is how the fields look in the `form.html.haml` for the view.

```
= f.label 'Expiry'
= f.text_field :expiry_month, placeholder: 'MM', maxlength: 2
= f.text_field :expiry_year, placeholder: 'YYYY', maxlength: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do it like this:

If you have an error class you can check for any errors and display the class in the view.

`.error { color: #9d1d20; }`

```
- if @donation.errors.messages.keys.any? { |k| k.match(/expiry/) }
  = f.label 'Expiry', class: "form-label-expiry error"
- else
  = f.label 'Expiry', class: "form-label-expiry"
  = f.text_field :expiry_month, autocomplete: "off"
  = f.text_field :expiry_year, autocomplete: "off"
```